# asp.net updatepanel

Tags: updatepanel, modalpopupextender, scriptmanager

I have update panel in Modal popup extender, and I have script manager in masterpage, but when I run the website, I get following error : 
    [InvalidOperationException: The control with ID 'udpOutterUpdatePanel' requires a     S

```
criptManager on the page. The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it.]
   System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel.get_ScriptManager() +303
   System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel.RegisterPanel() +170
   System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel.RegisterPanel() +132
   System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel.OnInit(EventArgs e) +53
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +605
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +323
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +323
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +323
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +323
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +323
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +323
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +323
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2241
```

When I add scriptmanager in my page it gives error as "Only one instance is allowed".
Please help me out of this.
I am using windows 7,vs2010

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your "Modal popup extender" is linked to the master page with "ContentPlaceHolderID" which contains the "ScriptManager" from the maste page ? so that it can load the "ScriptManager" !

```
<%@ ... MasterPageFile="~/MasterFile.master" .... %>

<asp:Content ID="myContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentScriptManager" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Thanks for your replies, the problem is solved.Script Manager was not at proper place in Master page.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add **ScriptManagerProxy** in content page, which enables nested components such as content pages to add script to pages when a ScriptManager control is already defined in a parent element.